# CSS paragraph min width when wrapping around images

Tags: html, css

Consider the following CSS / HTML :

```css
img.text-wrap-left {
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="text-wrap-left" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZUMt7sn_FTLfvRK-B4XHK46Zyxv4kaj4O60tVXVMAg2m8Ohj0CdfinbEUmkwzaGmUE8V0jmKXHxSOvegEk3M3urVLsEbAzzmpwj-kDs=s660" width="550">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a ultrices est. Morbi semper enim sit amet feugiat fermentum. Phasellus odio lorem, finibus sit amet nibh ut, lobortis scelerisque nisl. Vestibulum mattis, ligula vitae sodales maximus, metus arcu egestas ex, non ullamcorper leo metus et mi. Integer libero justo, commodo a augue et, tempus aliquam leo. Donec ac ex aliquet, auctor erat sit amet, gravida metus. Duis vel condimentum dolor. Maecenas id consequat massa, vel dictum turpis. Cras dignissim aliquet mauris eu facilisis. Donec malesuada arcu in nulla commodo aliquam.

Nunc in est eget justo fringilla blandit. Morbi leo nisl, sagittis nec nulla ut, accumsan tristique orci. Praesent quis nisl pharetra, tempus nisi ornare, laoreet velit. Aliquam at dolor at eros elementum rutrum. Quisque tincidunt tincidunt nisi id porta. Cras hendrerit egestas leo, sed ultrices lorem dapibus et. Duis consectetur nisi eget ligula condimentum malesuada. Sed venenatis nisi id facilisis vestibulum. Nam tristique massa quis ornare blandit. Vivamus lobortis orci velit.
</p>
```

When the viewport is resized, the text will wrap right of the image, but will also become very narrow, to the point of even having a few letters only.

Is it possible to specify the minimum width of the text before the paragraph just goes entirely under the image, all without sacrificing paddings and margins?

In this example, an easy solution would be to add a `media` CSS condition, and tell the image to `display:block;` at a certain width. The problem is that this is only an example; my problem is that the images that are used with the text may have variable widths (i.e. they are user defined) and I am looking for a responsive solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think better option is to use `max-width` on image to keep its max-width at some % and then also add media query to break text to new line at some point. [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/952/)

```css
img.text-wrap-left {
  float:left; 
  max-width: 50%;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  img.text-wrap-left {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img class="text-wrap-left" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZUMt7sn_FTLfvRK-B4XHK46Zyxv4kaj4O60tVXVMAg2m8Ohj0CdfinbEUmkwzaGmUE8V0jmKXHxSOvegEk3M3urVLsEbAzzmpwj-kDs=s660" width="550">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras a ultrices est. Morbi semper enim sit amet feugiat fermentum. Phasellus odio lorem, finibus sit amet nibh ut, lobortis scelerisque nisl. Vestibulum mattis, ligula vitae sodales maximus, metus arcu egestas ex, non ullamcorper leo metus et mi. Integer libero justo, commodo a augue et, tempus aliquam leo. Donec ac ex aliquet, auctor erat sit amet, gravida metus. Duis vel condimentum dolor. Maecenas id consequat massa, vel dictum turpis. Cras dignissim aliquet mauris eu facilisis. Donec malesuada arcu in nulla commodo aliquam.

Nunc in est eget justo fringilla blandit. Morbi leo nisl, sagittis nec nulla ut, accumsan tristique orci. Praesent quis nisl pharetra, tempus nisi ornare, laoreet velit. Aliquam at dolor at eros elementum rutrum. Quisque tincidunt tincidunt nisi id porta. Cras hendrerit egestas leo, sed ultrices lorem dapibus et. Duis consectetur nisi eget ligula condimentum malesuada. Sed venenatis nisi id facilisis vestibulum. Nam tristique massa quis ornare blandit. Vivamus lobortis orci velit.
</p>
```